# Copying charts to new workbook without links

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to copy certain sheets from a workbook into a new book.

Copying the relevant sheets works fine, however in the new workbook all of the charts are still linked to cells from the old workbook.

Does anyone know of an intuitive way of copying over sheets to a new book but having the charts source data from the new book?

Here is an example of how I'm copying the sheets over:

```
Sub copySheets()

' Copy over other sheets

oldBook.Sheets("Chart Workings").Copy Before:=newBook.Sheets(1)
With newBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .Value = .Value 'converts formulas to values
End With

End sub
```

[EDIT] Ideally a method that doesn't involve going into each chart and pointing the series at the new workbook as I have over 65 charts and this will take a while...

Comment: Redesign the charts in your VBA code so it is automated, or copy the source data sheet over and then overwrite with new data.

Comment: Is all the data laid out exactly the same?  Why not just create a new chart, using the new sheet data, then applying the same formatting?

Comment: use the properties of the chart you'll have in newBook.Sheets(1) to remove the sheet link there.

Comment: If you don't need to update the charts any further after they are moved, you might consider copying and pasting each chart as a picture.

Comment: `.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).formula`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I have 11 sheets, each with 5 charts on and it would be ideal if this could be automated rather than having to point each of the new charts at the data in the new workbook. Is this possible?

Comment: @Chrismas007 How can I ensure that it is automated by design?

Comment: Yes as @Nathan_Sav said... you can point the charts to new ranges using VBA.